# One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)

Tags: sharepoint-2013

1. I have stop and restart services(Sharepoint Administration & Sharepoint Timer Service)
2. I cleaned the Configuration Cache by using mentioned steps.

   Summary of the steps to clear the timer job:

   Stop SharePoint Timer service on all servers in the farm.
   Browse to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config{GUID} where the {GUID} folder contains a bunch of XML files and      NOT the files with a “.PERSITEDFILE” extension.
   Delete all the XML files
   Update the contents of the Cache.ini file to just say “1” (without quotes).
   Restart the SharePoint Timer service on each server
   Reanalyze the issue in Health Analyzer

Does anyone know why this keeps occurring and how I can stop it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all try and check your ULS Logs and see if there is any error that arise.

Secondly try and maybe check the event viewer on your SharePoint server to see if any errors are shown and make sure you have enough disk space available.

and also you might want to check this :[Clearing Timer Services](https://mundeep.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/clearing-timer-services/)

Let me know if you see any error post it here.

hope it helps.
Yotam.